# Read stdoutput of continuous QProcess in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, console, output, qprocess

I am having some problem regarding QProcess using Qt. I have connected the following function with the onClick event of a push button. Basically, I want to execute another file when this button is clicked, and get its output on my Qt program. This file `calculator` executes, displays some output, and then waits for an input from the user.

```
void runPushButtonClicked() {
    QProcess myprocess;
    myprocess.start("./calculator")
    myprocess.waitForFinished();
    QString outputData= myprocess.readStandardOutput();
    qDebug() << outputData;
}
```

In a scenario, when the `calculator` is such a file that only outputs some results and terminates eventually, this works perfect. But, in case when the calculator waits for some further input from the user after outputting some results, I get nothing in my `outputData`. In fact, `waitForFinished()` would time out, but even when I remove `waitForFinished()`, the  `outputData` would still be empty.

I have already tried some of the solutions available here on SO, but have been unable to handle this case. Any guidance will be much appreciated.

Comment: _I have already tried some of the solutions_ show what you have tried.

Comment: By connection of Signal and Slot :                                                        connect(process,SIGNAL(readyRead()),this,SLOT(readStdOut()));

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest, that you setup a signal handler, that gets called when the subprocess produces output. E.g. you have to connect to [`readyReadStandardOutput`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#readyReadStandardOutput).

Then you can identify, when subprocess demands input and send the input you want. This will be done in `readSubProcess()`.

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QtCore>
#include "Foo.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
   QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);

   Foo foo;

   qDebug() << "Starting main loop";
   app.exec();
}
```

In the following, the subprocess is started and the input checked. When the `calculator` program finishes, the main also exits.

**Foo.h**

```
#include <QtCore>

class Foo : public QObject {
   Q_OBJECT
   QProcess myprocess;
   QString output;

public:
   Foo() : QObject() {
      myprocess.start("./calculator");

      // probably nothing here yet
      qDebug() << "Output right after start:"
               << myprocess.readAllStandardOutput();

      // get informed when data is ready
      connect(&myprocess, SIGNAL(readyReadStandardOutput()),
              this, SLOT(readSubProcess()));
   };

private slots:
   // here we check what was received (called everytime new data is readable)
   void readSubProcess(void) {
      output.append(myprocess.readAllStandardOutput());
      qDebug() << "complete output: " << output;

      // check if input is expected
      if (output.endsWith("type\n")) {
         qDebug() << "ready to receive input";

         // write something to subprocess, if the user has provided input,
         // you need to (read it and) forward it here.
         myprocess.write("hallo back!\n");
         // reset outputbuffer
         output = "";
      }

      // subprocess indicates it finished
      if (output.endsWith("Bye!\n")) {
         // wait for subprocess and exit
         myprocess.waitForFinished();
         QCoreApplication::exit();
      }
   };
};
```

For the subprocess **calculator** a simple script is used. You can see the where output is generated and where input is expected.

```
#/bin/bash

echo "Sub: Im calculator!"

# some processing here with occasionally feedback
sleep 3
echo "Sub: hallo"

sleep 1

echo "Sub: type"
# here the script blocks until some input with '\n' at the end comes via stdin
read BAR

# just echo what we got from input
echo "Sub: you typed: ${BAR}"

sleep 1
echo "Sub: Bye!"
```

If you do not need to do anything else in your main process (e.g. show a GUI, manage other threads/processes....), the easiest would be to just in a `sleep` in a loop after subprocess creation and then something like `readSubprocess`.

Comment: Thanks for your time. The answer does not work for me because the "     qDebug() << "complete output: " << output; " never occur in my case. I donot know.

Comment: When i use execute instead of start it work but run in terminal not in console Output